# Changed email text after updating password for user in Wordpress Dashboard User settings does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to adjust text for email sent after updating password for user in Wordpress backend.

I did it in functions.php of my theme:

```
add_filter('password_change_email', 'change_code');
```

My function:

```
function change_code($pass_change_mail,$user,$userdata ){
    $new_message_txt = __( 'Some text ###USERNAME### more text even more text ###EMAIL### more text after more text last bit of text ###SITENAME###' );
    $pass_change_mail[ 'message' ] = $new_message_txt;
    return $pass_change_mail;
```

Actually I need to connect with this filter in user.php, which envoke somethoing like that:

```
$pass_change_email = apply_filters( 'password_change_email', $pass_change_email, $user, $userdata );
$pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###USERNAME###', $user['user_login'], $pass_change_email['message'] );
$pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###ADMIN_EMAIL###', get_option( 'admin_email' ), $pass_change_email['message'] );
$pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###EMAIL###', $user['user_email'], $pass_change_email['message'] );
$pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###SITENAME###', $blog_name, $pass_change_email['message'] );
$pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( '###SITEURL###', home_url(), $pass_change_email['message'] );
wp_mail( $pass_change_email['to'], sprintf( $pass_change_email['subject'], $blog_name ), $pass_change_email['message'], $pass_change_email['headers'] );
```

Maybe that code is not corrected and something better exists. Someone know, how to solve that, please?

Comment: That is the correct way to do it, with filters. I'm not understanding what it doesn't work. Can you add details to your question?

Comment: when I tested it ,, through mailcatcher, nothing will be showed  I am not sure with parameters of my filter.. according to you is that ok, please?

Comment: I debug my function, but it did not run

Comment: Ok, so I think your filter is the problem, you have to add parameters to the end of it: `add_filter('password_change_email', 'change_code', 10, 3);`. The 10 is the priority, the 3 is the number of arguments your function has: `function change_code($pass_change_mail,$user,$userdata ){`

Comment: I already solved it. My functions.php includes constructor()  and that filter was not recognized inside ... but outside constructor() filter worked correctly .. but thanks for your time  :)

Comment: No problem, glad it worked